# missing value issue caused by creating a new column using info from two datasets

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two large data sets like these:

```
df1=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 10)), day =c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15,19,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/16/2012 17:22','4/16/2012 17:45','4/16/2012 18:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/1/2012 16:28','5/1/2012 17:00','5/5/2012 17:00','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/23/2012 16:55','4/23/2012 17:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/8/2012 15:55','5/8/2012 16:30'))

df2=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)), day=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,9,9,15,15,1,1,2,2,3,3,9,9,15,15),dtime=c('4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 15:16','4/18/2012 7:15','4/18/2012 21:45','4/19/2012 7:05','4/19/2012 23:17','4/28/2012 7:15','4/28/2012 21:12','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 15:15','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/25/2012 6:45','4/25/2012 21:30','4/26/2012 6:45','4/26/2012 22:00','5/2/2012 7:00','5/2/2012 22:00','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 15:45'))
```

...

in df2, the 'dtime' contains two time points for each subject on each day. I want to use the time points for each sub on each day in df1 (ie. 'stime') to subtract the second time point for each sub on each day in df2, if the result is positive, then give the second time point in dtime for that observation, otherwise give the first time point. For example, for subject 1 on day 1, ('4/16/2012 6:25'-'4/16/2012 15:16')<0, so we give the first time point '4/16/2012 6:15' to this obs; ('4/16/2012 17:22'-'4/16/2012 15:16')>0,
so we give this second time point '4/16/2012 15:16' to this obs. The expected output should look like this:

```
df3=data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 10)), day =c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15,19,1,1,1,1,2,3,15,15,15,15),stime=c('4/16/2012 6:25','4/16/2012 7:01','4/16/2012 17:22','4/16/2012 17:45','4/16/2012 18:13','4/18/2012 6:50','4/19/2012 6:55','5/1/2012 6:28','5/1/2012 7:00','5/1/2012 16:28','5/1/2012 17:00','5/5/2012 17:00','4/23/2012 5:56','4/23/2012 6:30','4/23/2012 16:55','4/23/2012 17:20','4/25/2012 6:32','4/26/2012 6:28','5/8/2012 5:54','5/8/2012 6:30','5/8/2012 15:55','5/8/2012 16:30'), dtime=c('4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 6:15','4/16/2012 15:16','4/16/2012 15:16','4/16/2012 15:16','4/18/2012 7:15','4/19/2012 7:05','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 7:15','5/1/2012 15:15','5/1/2012 15:15','.','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 6:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/23/2012 16:45','4/25/2012 6:45','4/26/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 6:45','5/8/2012 15:45','5/8/2012 15:45'))
```

...

I used the code below to realize this, however, due to the missing 'dtime' for day 19, R kept giving me the error:

```
df1$dtime <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){  
                  choices <- df2[ df2$subject==as.numeric(x["subject"]) & 
                                       df2$day==as.numeric(x["day"]) , "dtime"]
         if( as.POSIXct(x["stime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < 
                 as.POSIXct(choices[2],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ) {
            choices[1] 
            }else{ choices[2] } 
                                  } )

Error in if (as.POSIXct(x["stime"], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") < as.POSIXct(choices[2],  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Since my datasets are large (about 15,000 rows and 30 columns), there are some missing 'dtime' in df2. Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you:

```
df1$dtime <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) {

  choices <- as.character(df2[ df2$subject==as.numeric(x["subject"]) & 
                  df2$day==as.numeric(x["day"]), "dtime"])

  t1 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(x["stime"]), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  t2 <- as.POSIXct(choices[2], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

  return(ifelse(( t1 < t2 ), choices[1], choices[2]))

})
```

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr, it worked for the datasets above. However when I run my large datasets, the 'dtime' column is full of 'NA'. Why this happened?